# Publish message to a specific Client ID

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, paho

Is it possible to publish message to a specific client id ?

I want to publish two things using mqtt:

1- General informations like users scores, stats etc ... and can be viewable by everyone.

2- Sensitive informations reserved for private user like own score, name etc ...

Is there any clean way to do it using Paho MQTT ?

By the way, using: https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang

Answer (score 0):

No, with the MQTT protocol messages are published to topics, not clients there can be anywhere between 0 and many clients subscribed to a given topic. Also there is no where in the message header to specify the target client id.

All clients subscribed to a topic will receive all messages published to that topic. But clients can subscribe to any number of topics so there is nothing to stop each client subscribing to a topic general topic and one that includes their clientid as an element in the topic. You can then use topic ACLs to ensure that only the client with the matching client id can subscribe to that topic.

Comment: What if there millions of users, generating and subscribing to all the topics will affect performances of server hardly... and is there any automatic way to add restrictions ACL automatically ? And how they can be set with rabbitmq please ? Thanks again for taking time to answer my question.

Comment: Topics are effemeral and only really exist at the point a message is published so there should be no performance overhead. As for the other points they are they are very specific to RabbitMQ and should be asked as separate questions.

Comment: I think publishing message to many different topics will affect the performance of rabbitmq server. Can you provide more infos related to this please ?

Comment: From the scenario you described in the original question you would still be publishing exactly the same number of messages, just to different topics. There would be negligible differences in performance.